# restrict IP traffic between VLAN sub-interfaces

Tags: iptables

I have a *router/firewall-PC* with two VLAN sub-interfaces *eth2.100* and *eth2.200*:

[image: router drawing]

I would like to allow communication between networks 192.168.100.0/24 and 192.168.300.0/24(PC3 network). In addition, I would like to allow communication between networks 192.168.200.0/24 and 192.168.300.0/24, but I would like to restrict communication between 192.168.100.0/24 and 192.168.200.0/24, i.e. between the networks configured to VLAN sub-interfaces. What is the most optimal way to achieve this? `iptables -A FORWARD -i eth2 -s 0.0.0.0/0 -d 192.168.300.0/24 -j ACCEPT` in *router/firewall-PC* with DROP FORWARD chain policy?

Comment: The less effort will be as you explained: Use `DROP` as the default policy to the `FORWARD` chain, and create rules like: `iptables -I FORWARD -i eth2.100 -d 192.168.300.0/24 -j ACCEPT`. It seems to be an overkill add the vlan input interface and the source (`-s`) since you are already limiting the L2 scope with vlans and L3 with your firewall